# Fragment's white background is displayed transparent

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

Activity behind the fragment is visible even after applying white background.

Fragment1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:clickable="true">
...

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how I am calling the fragment

```
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_frame, fragment, "Secondary_Fragment").addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

This is how I have used layout..

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, null);
    init(view);

    return view;
}
```

and color is

```
<color name="white">#ffffff</color>
```

Here is xml of main activity

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Issue is not visible on all the android versions. Yureka Plus with Cyanogen OS, Android 5.0.2 is showing this issue.

There is one more thing i observed.. if i use any other color than white.. issue doesn't appear.. is this problem with the device or some issue in my code ?

Comment: How did you define @color/white? Where do you use @layout/Fragment1?

Comment: @EugenPechanec edited the question with the details you asked

Comment: please post the code for your activity xml file.

Comment: @k2ibegin updated the question with activity's xml code..

Comment: The code looks very much correct. Would it be possible for you to post screenshots of what you're getting and what you need?

Comment: @EugenPechanec Ya.. I can post that.. There is one more thing i observed.. if i use any other color than white.. issue doesn't appear.. is this problem with the device or some issue in my code ?

Comment: In that case it's probably a bug in particular Android flavor for Yureka Plus.  As much as I don't like this solution using an "almost white" color like #fefefe might be the best option then.

Comment: Probably won't fix your problem but you don't have to define white as color since it is already included in system resources. Just use @android:color/white.

Comment: @sanju : did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, null);
    //set layout to the view
    view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    init(view);
    return view;
}
```